# $X$ is random variable (binomial, Poisson, Normal). Check distribution of $n-X$ for some $n> 0$

Tags: probability

Let $>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
**a.** $X$ has binomial distribution. It means that $Pr(X=k)={n\choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$.
Can we conclude that $n-X$ has also binomial distribution ?

**b.** $X$ has Poisson's distribution with $\lambda=\frac{n}{2}$. Can we conclude that $n-X$ has also Poisson's distribution ?
**c**. $X$ has normal distribution with parameters $\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2}$. Can we conclude that [tex]n-X[/tex] has also this distribution ?

I will try **a.**
Lets check for $n-X=1$
$Pr(n-X=1) = Pr(X=n-1) = {n\choose n-1}p^{n-1}(1-p)^{1}$
Ok, binomali distribution,
Lets check $Pr(n-X=n) = Pr(X=0) = {n\choose 0}p^{0}(1-p)^{n} = (1-p)^n$
So in **a.** answer is postive.

**b.**
$Pr(X=k) = \frac{(\frac{n}{2})^k}{k!}e^{-\frac{n}{2}}$
$Pr(n-X=k) = Pr(X=n-k) = \frac{(\frac{n}{2})^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}e^{-\frac{n}{2}}$
It seems to me that answer is negative, but I am not sure.
Can you help me with **c.** and **b.** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **a**. You are right: If $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$, then $n-X$ is also Binomially distributed, namely $n-X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,1-p)$. But your proof is not sufficient, with your approach you would need to check that for any $k$, not just $1$ and $n$. If you don't want to do that, observe that if $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$, then $X$ can be written $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where the $X_i$'s are independent Bernoulli with parameter $p$. But then,
$$
n-X = n- \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (1-X_i)
$$
and it is almost immediate to see that, with $Y_i\stackrel{\rm def}{=} 1-X_i$, the $Y_i$'s are independent Bernoulli with parameter $1-p$.

For **b**. A Poisson distribution is supported on the non-negative integers. If $X$ is Poisson (with *any* positive parameter), then it has non-zero probability of being greater than $n$, so $n-X$ has non-zero probability of being negative, and hence cannot be Poisson.

For **c**. Is it very easy* to show that if $X\sim\mathcal{G}(\mu,\sigma)$, then (i) for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $X+a  \sim\mathcal{G}(\mu+a,\sigma)$; and (ii) $-X\sim\mathcal{G}(-\mu,\sigma)$. *(Where I use the notation $\mathcal{G}(\mu,\sigma)$ for "Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.)*
Combining the two will give you the answer.

---

*${}$ If you don't see why, try proving it. It would be a good (and hopefully simple) exercise.

Comment: thanks, in **c** $n-X$ has also normal distribution

Comment: @HaskellFun Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

a) You should check it for $n-X=k$ where $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$. You can do it...

b) If $X$ has Poisson-distribution then  $\Pr(X>n)>0$ or equivalently $\Pr(n-X<0)>0$. This implies that $n-X$ has *no* Poisson-distribution, since for every Poisson-distributed $Z$ we have $\Pr(Z<0)=0$.

c) If $X$ has normal distribution, then so has $n-X$. Determine the parameters by finding mean and variance and compare to check whether it has the same distribution as $X$.